# How to access QTextEdit "layout" to add "status bar"?

Tags: qt

This a modified question I  have posted on this forum.
It is not a repost, for two reasons - I cannot edit the other post and I am trying to
resolve this issue from another angle. Besides the other post got derailed by people who mean well but did not really read the post.

I have a working C++ code which is using (QT) QTextEdit class to  collect and process text data.
The class - as its name suggest - was designed to collect and analyze  text.
The text is displayed in "view " area.
My task is to select ONE word of text and drag it to another GUI object.
I like to put the text being dragged into QT standard "status bar".

Normal QT GUI widgets are designed using QTDesigner. Integral part of such design process
is "layout".

As it stands , QTextEdit DOES NOT HAVE / USE "layout" or use it but it is NOT visible / accessible when QTextEdit is implemented  - there is no need for it.

In order to add "status bar" I need to MODIFY the view to hold the current text editing
"layout" and add "status bar " layout.

I am unable to figure out how to get access to the QTextEdit class GUI layout.
I  am asking for help to accomplish that- **how to add "status bar" to EXISTING QTextEdit.**

Please read the post carefully _ I need help with **how to add "status bar" to EXISTING QTextEdit.**

I do have an option to replace the QTextEdit with basic "widget" class but it "breaks " the working code and I rather not do that.

I did look into setting multiple inheritance - Qwidget and QTextEdit but did not work.

PLEASE Mr Higgins , editing my post for proper English grammar and composition DOES NOT solve the problem. So , please - don't.

Comment: I think you would make a layout object using one of the classes provided by Qt, then add the QTextEdit AND the status bar to that layout, and then set you window to use that layout.

Comment: As posted   I do have an option to replace the QTextEdit with basic "widget" class but it "breaks " the working code and I rather not do that.

Comment: I'm not talking about replacing the QTextEdit, just changing the way it is added to your window.  Whatever pointers you have that point to the QTextEdit can be maintained; no need to replace them.  Unless you have a lot of code that takes the QTextEdit and moves it to different parents I don't see how this breaks anything.  Maybe post a sample of the code that breaks and an estimate of how many lines will break.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add "status bar" to QT widget - without using QTDesigner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74083627/how-to-add-status-bar-to-qt-widget-without-using-qtdesigner)

Comment: you didn't ask it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74083627/9484913) before? you should update the previous one or add comments in answers. if the answer was correct you should check the green tick or you can upvote it, by these ways we can help you and also understand the problem. I mean other users need feedback to understand or help you.

Comment: You are thinking of this the wrong way around. You should not be adding new visual stuff inside a `QTextEdit`. You should be putting a `QTextEdit` into something new. You should only subclass if you _need_ to override some of the protected methods (that is, reacting to signals from the `QTextEdit` or the `QTextDocument` are not good enough).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure but your question seems to imply that inheriting from `QTextEdit` would be acceptable.  If that's the case then you can probably make use of the fact that `QTextEdit` itself inherits `QAbstractScrollArea` and use the [viewport margins](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractscrollarea.html#setViewportMargins) to create an area in which to show a status bar of some sort.

Consider the following code...

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QScrollBar>
#include <QStatusBar>
#include <QTextEdit>

namespace {
  class text_edit: public QTextEdit {
    using super = QTextEdit;
  public:
    explicit text_edit (QWidget *parent = nullptr)
      : super(parent)
      , m_status(this)
      {
        m_status.setStyleSheet("background-color: gray;");
        m_status.showMessage("Status text goes here...");
        show_status(true);
        horizontalScrollBar()->installEventFilter(this);
        verticalScrollBar()->installEventFilter(this);
        setLineWrapMode(QTextEdit::NoWrap);
      }
  protected:
    virtual bool eventFilter (QObject *obj, QEvent *event) override
      {
        if (event->type() == QEvent::Show || event->type() == QEvent::Hide)
          update_status_geometry();
        return super::eventFilter(obj, event);
      }
    virtual void resizeEvent (QResizeEvent *event) override
      {
        super::resizeEvent(event);
        update_status_geometry();
      }
  private:
    void show_status (bool on)
      {
        if (on) {
          setViewportMargins(0, 0, 0, m_status.height());
          m_status.show();
        } else {
          setViewportMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
          m_status.hide();
        }
      }
    void update_status_geometry ()
      {

        /*
         * Calculate initial geometry of the QStatusBar based on its size hint.
         */
        auto s = m_status.sizeHint();
        s.rwidth() = width();
        QRect geom(QPoint(0, 0), s);
        geom.moveTop(height() - s.height());

        /*
         * Adjust the status bar geometry to allow for the scroll bars.
         */
        if (horizontalScrollBar()->isVisible())
          geom.moveTop(geom.top() - horizontalScrollBar()->height());
        if (verticalScrollBar()->isVisible())
          geom.setRight(geom.right() - verticalScrollBar()->width());
        m_status.setGeometry(geom);
      }
    QStatusBar m_status;
  };
}

int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  text_edit te;
  te.show();
  return app.exec();
}
```

Running the code above results in the following widget...

[image]

Comment: I believe your suggestion is the solution. Thanks. I need to brush up on few C++ basics before I can implement it. I have tried replacing the QTextEdit with QWidget but it broke my code function big time. .

Comment: I am not sure how to carry on a discussion here.

Comment: Well, you really shouldn't start a discussion as such -- that's not what SO is for.  If you have a question regarding the answer I've provided I'll take a look.

Comment: OK will do. Latter.